# DatePicker shortdate mask

Tags: wpf, datepicker, mask

I want the DatePicker WPF control to behave as a Windows Forms date masked textbox.
Basically, I want to have the --/--/---- mask so as to restrict the user to fill the blanks correctly. Also, the "/" must be static because I don´t want the user to be adding these symbols manually. What I did early, was to convert a number as a date, for example 01012013 to 01/01/2013. But this notation is not friendly to the user. I´m really surprised that WPF is not providing any native masking. Can somebody put me in the right track with this issue? I was about to add the "/" based in the length of the DatePicker text, but I wanted to ask first.

This is the example what I want to achieve:

[image]